# Good smartphone optical zoom

Tags: smartphones, camera, video-camera, ip-camera

What's a good smart phone optical zoom lens? I see many but not sure which one is good. Also would monocular or spotting scope work better? I won't be using it for smartphone. Will be using it in front of wyze v3 to zoom into a peephole without opening v3. Right now all I see is white light. But for my note 10 optical zoom is great when seeing though the peephole I can see pretty much everything.

Comment: If you want to have best optical zoom, you want a dedecated camera with extra zoom lens, but I really don't know which model you want to look for

Comment: You would need something made specifically for your camera, otherwise it won't focus.